# how to fix email outgoing server in vtiger 7.1.0 in localhost

Tags: php, vtigercrm

> error Test Mail Status : Mail could not be sent to the admin user.
>   Please check the admin emailid/Server settings.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure to allow less secure apps on your gmail.
   https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
2. Make sure to put email address into "From Email". It will only work if you put in the same as the gmail email address (it's gmail restriction). *This only applies to Gmail.

VTExperts

Comment: okay, less secure apps in Gmail allowed. And from mail is Gmail account which is enabled with less secure in entered in From Email but I get this error: Test Mail Status : Mail could not be sent to the admin user. Please check the admin emailid/Server settings